# Why I am not able to use Image button that are defined in a function

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#Import python tkinter and Image library
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
#making function
def func():
    top = Tk()
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = 'my_image.png')
    b1 = Button(top, image=image).grid(row=0, column=0)
    top.mainloop()
#main
win = Tk()
#I want this button to open another window where it shows a button with an Image on it. 
b2 = Button(top, text='Click to open new window', command=func).grid(row=0, column=0)
win.mainloop()

#Output
#pyimage1 doesn't exist.
```

It should have shown a window with a button that takes me to another window where there is an image button.
This should have worked but in mine, it shows the above output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: Actually, what @Matiiss linked to is certainly part of the problem, but multiple calls to `Tk()` are also an issue here - use `Toplevel()` to create additional windows.